# How to get the time of the recording while recording with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia, media-source, web-mediarecorder

I am writing a simple web app that captures the audio coming from the mic with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` and records it with a `MediaRecorder` object. I am more or less following the [example from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API).

I would like to add a live display of the time of the recording. I am currently relying on `performance.now()`, which is not very elegant, even more so because I allow the user to pause/resume the `MediaRecorder`. Is there a way to get the time directly from the `MediaRecorder` object itself somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only solution is to track the recorded time yourself. The `MediaRecorder` object does not provide such an attribute.

[This npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/durations) might be of help.

You should listen on `start`, `resume`, `stop` and `pause` events.